# Drag and fill table on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a Game of Life using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  I don't want to use jQuery.

So, I have to setup the initial state, which is to make an element on the table having the color green when we click over it.  I do this by toggling the class 'alive' that has background-color 'green' whenever an element in the table is clicked.

However, it is a bit tedious to click each element.  Is there a way that we can make this draggable? I want when you click your left mouse and drag it across the table it will append the class 'alive' to each of the element.

Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You should include some of your code in the question so we can help you fix it, not just give it all to you. Here's a hint: `onmousedown` start tracking the mouse's location (using `onmousemove`), when it leaves the bounds of the current square check to see what square it's in and change the classes to match. That simple!

Comment: also, massive dom updates are slow, may be canvas will be faster for you.

Comment: I see. okay, I will try to look on onmousedown and onmousemove.

I prefer the table approach, not canvas.  It is just part of the requirement